# nginx direct trafic to non domain name using IP and local names

Tags: nginx, server, host, server-name

Using nginx on windows server I want to direct traffic into different ports using names that are non-domain names, first one works but second one never reach: why? what is wrong?
http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/game: works 
http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/cms: never reach.
If I change names then cms works and game never reach.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  game;
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
location /uploads/ {
        root c:\Ebrahimi\www\appGame;
}
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  cms;
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2010;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
location /uploads/ {
        root c:\Ebrahimi\www\appCms;
}
}
```

---

New code block as "Richard Smith" mentioned:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
location /uploads/ {
        root c:\Ebrahimi\www\appGame;
}
location /game {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
}
location /cms{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2010;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `server` block can only be accessed using its `server_name`, for example: `http://app.firouzeh-mfg.ir/`

If you are accessing your server using its IP address, the request will be processed by the first `server` block (or the block marked as the `default_server`). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Your two URLs `http://192.x.x.x/game` and `http://192.x.x.x/cms` (assuming identical IP addresses) access the same `server` block and differ only by `location`.

For example:

```
server {
    location /game {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
    }
    location /cms{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2010;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- sorry for mistake in code block 2, edited. 2- Both ports are on the same machine and through ports point to diff project.